# sed treating filename as pattern?

Tags: php, macos, apache, bash, sed

I have the following sed command to comment out phpinfo() from my index.php:

```
sudo sed -i "s/phpinfo();/\/\/phpinfo();/g" index.php
```

But it gives me:

```
$ sudo sed -i "s/phpinfo();/\/\/phpinfo();/g" index.php
sed: 1: "index.php": command i expects \ followed by text
```

If I try to specify the entire path, it does the same thing:

```
sed: 1: "/Library/WebServer/Docu ...": invalid command code W
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Evident? How? I edited my question and copied it straight from bash. Verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sed:

```
sudo sed -i.bak "s~phpinfo();~//phpinfo();~g" index.php
```

- Older sed versions need file extension with `-i` flag
- Better to use an alternative regex delimiter to avoid escaping `/`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. The Unix end of OS X must be a bit outdated because this isn't the first time I've been hit by an out-of-date command.

Comment: I feel your pain as I am on OSX too :) but I have also installed homebrew and all newer gnu versions like gsed, gawk etc.